# How to Load a Stored HTML with relative Paths

Tags: webview

I would like to load a stored webview with this line

```
[wvTop loadHTMLString:ev.htmlEventTop baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER]];
```

it works as it should, but now I have some troubles to display images with relative paths.

How can I load the html an tell where to look for the files?

Comment: Are you loading the HTML from the assets folder?

Comment: No the html gets stored in a db

Comment: root/files/<relativepathfromhtml>

Comment: I was asking where you stored your images. Are they stored as Assets in your system? Then you just need to use 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374553/android-webview-loaddatawithbaseurl-how-load-images-from-assets