# Android - save value on LocalStorage before WebView.loadUrl()

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, local-storage

Before I load a URL on WebView i want to set a value inside browser LocalStorage.

Till now the only way I did managed to set this value is after the page is loaded. This is how I can set the value:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loadUrl("javascript: LocalStorage.set('namespace', 'key', 'value');");
        }
}
```

I did try to override the method `onPageStarted()`, but the value is not stored.

How can I set this key/value before the call `browser.loadUrl()`? The url/page depends on this value, so I need to set the value before I load the page.

Comment: why not using SharedPreferences (for example), if you want to store things...?

Comment: I need to save data inside Webview, so Webpage javascript can read it. I don't see how SharedPreferences can solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is set a redirect into the `javascript` to the actual url and load the javascript plus redirect using `webview.loadData()`.

```
 String injection = "<html><head><script type='javascript'>LocalStorage.set('namespace', 'key', 'value');window.location.replace('YOUR_URL_HERE');</script></head><body></body></html>";
 webview.loadData(injection, "text/html", null);
```

Be aware though that you might need to save that to a file first before it works: see [How to load a javascript redirect into android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660421/how-to-load-a-javascript-redirect-into-android-webview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebViewClient.onPageStarted() for this.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        String js = "window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 2022 still working