# Using android vector drawable inside HTML

Tags: android, html, svg, android-webview, drawable

I need to display a `vector drawable` which is present in `drawable` folder in a `WebView`. This is for a native android app.

If I use the code:

```
 <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/example.png"/>
```

It works for `png/jpeg` images, but is there any way to display `vector drawable` (with `.xml` extension) inside a `WebView`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537751/android-how-to-load-a-vector-drawable-image-into-a-webview

Comment: first **[get bitmap from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable)** Than **[display that bitmap in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849200/android-how-to-display-a-bitmap-in-a-webview)**